# Get Eclipse to prefer static imports of nested classes

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

Assume we have a class `FooCollection` which contains a somewhat long list of static nested classes*:

```
public class FooCollection {
    public static class FooA implements Foo {
        // ...
    }

    public static class FooB implements Foo {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Assume now we have another class using all of these classes. Currently, Eclipse will auto-format this to import each class separately if we reference the class itself

```
import com.me.FooCollection.FooA;
import com.me.FooCollection.FooB;
import com.me.FooCollection.FooC;
import com.me.FooCollection.FooD;

// and then later something like
callBaz( FooA.class );
```

What I would prefer to avoid bloating imports and constant commits changing imports due to colleagues using IntelliJ, is having it imported as

```
import static com.me.FooCollection.*;
```

However, I can't seem to find anything to get Eclipse to do this. Is there something I am missing or any way to get Eclipse to do it this way?

*Edit:* I actually just checked and even `new FooA()` will still cause the imports to switch back to this, despite setting the start imports threshold.

<sub>*) I realize that this is not exactly a good design, but it's a legacy application and for the sake of it let's assume that the code cannot be changed.</sub>

Comment: Is this setting separate (or non-existent) from the normal "organize imports" where it sets the number of imports which triggers the `*` usage?

Comment: Yes, because that setting will only work for methods, unfortunately.

Comment: It seems that you get what you want with Eclipse Mars... though there is still no setting to control the behavior :-)

Answer (score 2):

Dave Newton is referencing the setting under "Organize Imports" in Window -> Preferences.  You can set the threshold for importing using a wildcard.  Looks like the default is 99 classes before going to the wildcard.  If you set it at 2, it looks like it would do what you needed!

Comment: Sorry, my question was not precise enough – my bad! I know this setting, but it won't apply if the class is directly referenced like `FooA.class`.

Comment: "Edit:" This setting seems to only affect methods, not static classes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if there is a way to make it to work globally, but there is a short cut to deal with one member at a time.

If you select `FooCollection.FooA` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>  will add the static import and also will update all other references with in that file.

I use this mostly to import Enums and constants.

Comment: This works fine for methods, but if I reference the class directly as `FooA.class` (my bad for not mentioning), it won't work.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.. I thought it would work, just tested and its not working.

Comment: I just checked, it doesn't work for static classes at all, even if not referenced by class.